# Finding the spanning subgraphs of a complete bipartite graph

Tags: graph-theory, bipartite-graphs

Let $K_{(m,n)}$ be the complete bipartite graph with $m$ and $n$ being the number of vertices in each partition. Is there an efficient way to list down or construct all its spanning subgraphs up to isomorphism?

I tried finding the spanning subgraphs for small $m$ and $n$ and what I am doing is I start by distributing edges. The number of edges is greater than or equal to $0$ and less than or equal to $mn$. There is only one spanning subgraph with $0$ and $mn$ edges. There is only one spanning subgraph with $1$ edge also. For $2$ edges there are two if $m+n\geq 4$ and only one otherwise. Then I proceed until I have used up all the possible number of edges. This is quite tedious.

Can anyone suggest an alternative method? I figured some programs might be able to enumerate all the spanning subgraphs fast so there must be a way on how they do it.

Any help or idea is appreciated. Thank you!

UPDATE:

I'm also interested on the number of these graphs. How many spanning subgraphs does $K_{(m,n)}$ have? I've read somewhere that I should use Polya's Enumeration Theorem. I'm not yet familiar on how to use that. I'd be really thankful if someone could give a hint and point me to the right direction. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Introductory remark.**  The following discussion  uses two different
definition  of spanning  subgraphs of  $K_{n,m}$, one  being subgraphs
with the same vertex set and the second subgraphs with the same vertex
set  where there  are  no isolated  vertices.  The first  of these  is
equivalent to coloring the graph with two colors. Call these two model
$Q$ and model $P$ respectively.

The goal here is to enumerate spanning subgraphs of $K_{n,m}$ where we
will treat  the simple  case where  even if $n=m$  there are  no flips
above a  central vertical axis i.e.   no reflections.  We  can do much
better than NAUTY  as we are only counting these  graphs as opposed to
enumerating them. We use the Polya Enumeration Theorem (PET) to obtain
the count of all non-isomorphic subgraphs of $K_{n,m}$ (model $Q$) and
the principle of inclusion-exclusion (PIE) to extract the count of the
spanning subgraphs (model $P$).

We  will consult  NAUTY just  the  same to  get sample  data to  match
against in  our mathematical analysis.  The following Perl  script was
used.

```
#! /usr/bin/perl -w
#

sub decode_graph {
    my ($str) = @_;

    sub R {
        my (@args) = map {
            sprintf "%06b", $_;
        } @_;
        join '', @args;
    }

    my (@ents) = map {
        ord($_) - 63 
    } split //, $str;

    my $n = shift @ents;
    my @adj_data = split //, R(@ents);

    my $adj = []; my $pos = 0;
    for(my $ind2 = 1; $ind2 < $n; $ind2++){
        for(my $ind1 = 0; $ind1 < $ind2; $ind1++){
            $adj->[$ind1]->[$ind2] = $adj_data[$pos];
            $adj->[$ind2]->[$ind1] = $adj_data[$pos];

            $pos++;
        }
    }

    return $adj;
}

MAIN: {
    my $mx = shift || 3;

    die "out of range for GENBG: $mx" 
        if 2*$mx < 2 || 2*$mx > 32;

    for(my $comp_a = 1; $comp_a <= $mx; $comp_a++){
        for(my $comp_b = 1; $comp_b <= $mx; $comp_b++){

            my $vcount = $comp_a + $comp_b;

            my $cmd = sprintf "./genbg %d %d",
            $comp_a, $comp_b;

            my $count = 0;

            open GENBG, "$cmd 2>/dev/null|";
            while(my $bp = <GENBG>){
                chomp $bp; my $adj = decode_graph $bp;

                for($v = 0; $v < $vcount; $v++){
                    my $deg = 0;
                    for(my $w = 0; $w < $vcount; $w++){
                        my $ent = $adj->[$v]->[$w];
                        $deg++ if defined($ent) && $ent == 1;
                    }

                    last if $deg == 0;
                }

                $count++ if $v == $vcount;
            }
            close GENBG;

            printf " " if $comp_b > 1;
            printf "%06d", $count;
        }
        printf "\n";
    };
}
```

This gave the following table:

```
$ ./scripts/bipartite.pl 6
000001 000001 000001 000001 000001 000001
000001 000003 000005 000008 000011 000015
000001 000005 000017 000042 000091 000180
000001 000008 000042 000179 000633 002001
000001 000011 000091 000633 003835 020755
000001 000015 000180 002001 020755 200082
```

Now  for the  mathematics. We  use  the Polya  Enumeration Theorem  as
conjectured  by the OP.  To do  this we  need the  cycle index  of the
action  on  the edges  of  the group  that  permutes  the vertices  in
partition $A$ of  size $n$ according to the  symmetric group $S_n$ and
the vertices in partition $B$ of size $m$ according to $S_m.$

These cycle indices are easy to  compute and we do not need to iterate
over all $n!\times  m!$ pairs of permutations (acting  on $A$ and $B$)
but instead it  is sufficient to iterate over pairs  of terms from the
cycle indices $Z(S_n)$ and $Z(S_m)$  of the symmetric groups $S_n$ and
$S_m$  according to  their multiplicities  to obtain  the  cycle index
$Z(Q_{n,m})$  of the combined  action on  $A$ and  $B$. The  number of
terms here is the much better count of the number of partitions of $n$
and $m$ (upper bound).

The  classic approach  to the  calculation of  these cycle  indices is
based on  the simple  observation that for  two cycles, one  of length
$l_1$ from a  permutation $\alpha$ of $A$ and  another of length $l_2$
from a  column permutation  $\beta$ of $B$  their contribution  to the
disjoint cycle decomposition product for $(\alpha,\beta)$ in the cycle
index $Z(Q_{n,m})$ is by inspection

$$a_{\mathrm{lcm}(l_1, l_2)}^{l_1 l_2 / \mathrm{lcm}(l_1, l_2)} 
= a_{\mathrm{lcm}(l_1, l_2)}^{\gcd(l_1, l_2)}.$$

Once we have the cycle indices we evaluate
$$Z(Q_{n,m})(1+z)$$
which is the standard substitution to produce the OGF. If we are only
looking to obtain the count, we may use
$$Z(Q_{n,m})_{\Large a_1=a_2=a_3=\cdots=2}.$$

Here is an example:
$$Z(Q_{3,4}) =
{\frac {{a_{{1}}}^{12}}{144}}+1/24\,{a_{{2}}}^{3}{a_{{1}}}^{6}+1/18\,{a_{{3
}}}^{3}{a_{{1}}}^{3}+1/12\,{a_{{2}}}^{6}+1/6\,{a_{{4}}}^{3}
\\+1/48\,{a_{{2}}}
^{4}{a_{{1}}}^{4}+1/8\,{a_{{1}}}^{2}{a_{{2}}}^{5}+1/6\,a_{{1}}a_{{2}}a_{{3}
}a_{{6}}+1/8\,{a_{{3}}}^{4}
\\+1/12\,{a_{{3}}}^{2}a_{{6}}+1/24\,{a_{{6}}}^{2}+
1/12\,a_{{12}}.$$
The substituted cycle index becomes
$$Z(Q_{3,4})(1+z) =
{z}^{12}+{z}^{11}+3\,{z}^{10}+6\,{z}^{9}+11\,{z}^{8}
\\ +13\,{z}^{7}+17\,{z}^{6
}+13\,{z}^{5}+11\,{z}^{4}+6\,{z}^{3}+3\,{z}^{2}+z+1.$$

At this point we have just  about everything we need, the only problem
as is evident from the substituted cycle index (indexed by edge count)
is that we  are counting all subgraphs including  those that obviously
cannot span $K_{3,4}.$ Observe  however that $Z(Q_{3,4})$ includes the
count from all  graphs $K_{a,b}$ where $1\le a \le 3$  and $1\le b \le
4$ and this observation holds for the $Z(Q_{a,b})$ as well. The way to
identify a spanning subgraph of  $K_{3,4}$ is that every vertex in the
vertex set  has degree at  least one, which  means these are  just the
graphs  that cannot possibly be counted by $Z(Q_{a,b})$ with $(a,b)\ne
(3,4)$ because of the missing  vertices. Therefore we apply PIE to the
poset  where the  nodes corresponding  to the  $(a,b)$ is  the  set of
graphs counted by the  corresponding substituted cycle index.  We have
by inspection  that this poset is  isomorphic to the  divisor poset of
$2^{n-1}\times 3^{m-1}$  so that we  may use the  ordinary Möbius
function from  number theory as  our Möbius function for  the PIE
computation. (We are not including the  empty graph in the sets at the
nodes from the poset.)

This is implemented in the following Maple program.

```
with(numtheory);

pet_cycleind_symm :=
proc(n)
option remember;

    if n=0 then return 1; fi;

    expand(1/n*add(a[l]*pet_cycleind_symm(n-l), l=1..n));
end;

pet_varinto_cind :=
proc(poly, ind)
local subs1, subsl, polyvars, indvars, v, pot;

    polyvars := indets(poly);
    indvars := indets(ind);

    subsl := [];

    for v in indvars do
        pot := op(1, v);

        subs1 :=
        [seq(polyvars[k]=polyvars[k]^pot,
             k=1..nops(polyvars))];

        subsl := [op(subsl), v=subs(subs1, poly)];
    od;

    subs(subsl, ind);
end;


pet_cycleind_knm :=
proc(n, m)
    option remember;
    local cind, sind1, sind2, t1, t2, q,
    v1, v2, len, len1, len2;

    cind := 0;

    if n=1 then
        sind1 := [a[1]];
    else
        sind1 := pet_cycleind_symm(n);
    fi;

    if m=1 then
        sind2 := [a[1]];
    else
        sind2 := pet_cycleind_symm(m);
    fi;

    for t1 in sind1 do
        for t2 in sind2 do
            q := 1;

            for v1 in indets(t1) do
                len1 := op(1, v1);

                for v2 in indets(t2) do
                    len2 := op(1, v2);

                    len := lcm(len1, len2);
                    q := q *
                    a[len]^((len1*len2/len) *
                    degree(t1, v1)*degree(t2, v2));
                od;
            od;

            cind := cind +
            lcoeff(t1)*lcoeff(t2)*q;
        od;
    od;

    cind;
end;


v_pre_pie :=
proc(n, m)
    option remember;
    local cind;

    cind := pet_cycleind_knm(n, m);
    subs([seq(a[v]=2, v=1..n*m)], cind);
end;

v :=
proc(n, m)
    local q, a, b, res;

    q := 2^(n-1)*3^(m-1);

    res := 0;
    for a to n do
        for b to m do
            res := res +
            mobius(q/2^(a-1)/3^(b-1))*
            (v_pre_pie(a, b)-1);
        od;
    od;

    res;
end;

print_table :=
proc(mx)
    local n, m;

    for n to mx do
        for m to mx do
            if m>1 then printf(" ") fi;
            printf("%06d", v(n, m));
        od;

        printf("\n");
    od;
end;
```

The above Maple code produces the following table:

```
> print_table(6);
000001 000001 000001 000001 000001 000001
000001 000003 000005 000008 000011 000015
000001 000005 000017 000042 000091 000180
000001 000008 000042 000179 000633 002001
000001 000011 000091 000633 003835 020755
000001 000015 000180 002001 020755 200082
```

It can  calculate values  that are completely  out of reach  for NAUTY
like the  sequence of  non-isomorphic spanning subgraphs  of $K_{n,n}$
which is
$$1, 3, 17, 179, 3835, 200082, 29610804, 13702979132, \\
20677458750966, 103609939177198046, 1745061194503344181714, \\
99860890306900024150675406,\ldots$$
which points us to [OEIS A054976](https://oeis.org/A054976)
where we find confirmation of the above calculation and a slightly
different interpretation of the problem statement.

The function **v**  in the Maple program implements  model $P$ and the
function **v_pre_pie** implements model $Q.$

For bicolored versions of $K_{n,n}$ model $Q$ gives the sequence
$$2, 7, 36, 317, 5624, 251610, 33642660, 14685630688, \\
21467043671008, 105735224248507784, 1764356230257807614296, \\
100455994644460412263071692,\ldots$$
which points us to [OEIS A002724](https://oeis.org/A002724),
where the calculation is confirmed.

This [MSE Meta Link](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1868/list-of-generalizations-of-common-questions#13335) 
has many more PET computations by various users.

Thanks go to the authors of the NAUTY package.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks for taking the time to answer. I'm studying it right now. Quick question about 'the sequence of non-isomorphic spanning subgraphs of $K_{(n,n)}$. If I take $n=2$ I found that there are $6$ spanning subgraphs of $K_{(2,2)}$ namely: the empty graph of four vertices, $P_2\cup \{a\}\cup\{b\}, P_2\cup P_2, P_3\cup \{a\}, P_4, K_{(2,2)}$. Thank you!

Comment: We already discussed this at your other [MSE question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1160187/). There seven bicolored graphs on $K_{2,2}$ but a bicolored graph is not the same as a spanning subgraph. Please consult the discussion on the other question. E.g. the empty graph does not span $K_{2,2}.$ This [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_graph_theory#Subgraphs)  is the definition of a spanning subgraph. The above program also counts bicolored graphs. Note that **v_pre_pi(2,2)=7**  and **v(2,2)=3.**

Comment: I see what you mean now, I have added a comment.

Comment: I'm not impressed to have yet another impressing anwer from you.

Answer (score 3):

The following data augment those in  the first answer, namely we treat
the problem  of computing  $Z(Q_{n})$ for  $K_{n,n}$ where  we include
reflections. The algorithm here is  slightly different from Harary and
Palmer. Clearly all permutations from  the first answer represented in
$Z(Q_{n,n})$ contribute as  well.  Now for the  reflections, which are
simple, fortunately.  These (the vertex permutations)  can be obtained
from the permutations in $S_n$  by placing vertices from component $A$
alternating with component  $B$ on a cycle with twice  the length of a
cycle contained in a permutation $\gamma$ of $S_n.$ The induced action
on the set of edges is  the contribution to $Z(Q_n).$ In the following
we  have used  an algorithmic  approach rather  than the  formula from
Harary and Palmer,  namely we construct a  canonical representative of
each permutation shape from the  cycle index $Z(S_n)$ that doubles the
length  of   every  cycle  and   alternates  elements  from   the  two
components. We let that act on the set of edges and factor the result.

This gives the following cycle indices, the first of which matches the
result given by Harary and Palmer.
For $n=3$,
$$Z(Q_3) =
{\frac {{a_{{1}}}^{9}}{72}}+1/6\,{a_{{1}}}^{3}{a_{{2}}}^{3}
\\+1/8\,a_{{1}}{a_{{2}}}^{4}+1/4\,a_{{1}}{a_{{4}}}^{2}+1/9\,{
a_{{3}}}^{3}+1/3\,a_{{3}}a_{{6}}
,$$
for $n=4$,
$$Z(Q_4) =
{\frac {{a_{{1}}}^{16}}{1152}}+{\frac {{a_{{1}}}^{8}{a_{{2}
}}^{4}}{96}}+{\frac {5\,{a_{{1}}}^{4}{a_{{2}}}^{6}}{96}}\\+{
\frac {{a_{{1}}}^{4}{a_{{3}}}^{4}}{72}}+{\frac {17\,{a_{{2}
}}^{8}}{384}}+1/12\,{a_{{1}}}^{2}a_{{2}}{a_{{3}}}^{2}a_{{6}
}+1/8\,{a_{{1}}}^{2}a_{{2}}{a_{{4}}}^{3}\\+1/18\,a_{{1}}{a_{{
3}}}^{5}+1/6\,a_{{1}}a_{{3}}{a_{{6}}}^{2}+1/24\,{a_{{2}}}^{
2}{a_{{6}}}^{2}+{\frac {19\,{a_{{4}}}^{4}}{96}}+1/12\,a_{{4
}}a_{{12}}+1/8\,{a_{{8}}}^{2}
,$$
and for $n=5$,
$$Z(Q_5) =
{\frac {{a_{{1}}}^{25}}{28800}}+{\frac {{a_{{1}}}^{15}{a_{{
2}}}^{5}}{1440}}+{\frac {{a_{{1}}}^{9}{a_{{2}}}^{8}}{288}}+
{\frac {{a_{{1}}}^{10}{a_{{3}}}^{5}}{720}}+{\frac {{a_{{1}}
}^{5}{a_{{2}}}^{10}}{192}}\\+{\frac {{a_{{1}}}^{3}{a_{{2}}}^{
11}}{96}}+{\frac {a_{{1}}{a_{{2}}}^{12}}{128}}+{\frac {{a_{
{1}}}^{6}{a_{{2}}}^{2}{a_{{3}}}^{3}a_{{6}}}{72}}+{\frac {{a
_{{1}}}^{4}{a_{{3}}}^{7}}{72}}\\+{\frac {{a_{{1}}}^{5}{a_{{4}
}}^{5}}{480}}+1/24\,{a_{{1}}}^{3}{a_{{2}}}^{3}{a_{{4}}}^{4}
+{\frac {{a_{{2}}}^{5}{a_{{3}}}^{5}}{720}}+1/48\,{a_{{1}}}^
{3}a_{{2}}{a_{{4}}}^{5}\\+1/48\,{a_{{1}}}^{2}{a_{{2}}}^{4}a_{
{3}}{a_{{6}}}^{2}+{\frac {{a_{{2}}}^{5}{a_{{3}}}^{3}a_{{6}}
}{72}}+1/32\,a_{{1}}{a_{{2}}}^{2}{a_{{4}}}^{5}\\+1/48\,{a_{{2
}}}^{5}a_{{3}}{a_{{6}}}^{2}+1/36\,{a_{{2}}}^{2}{a_{{3}}}^{5
}a_{{6}}+1/12\,{a_{{1}}}^{2}a_{{2}}a_{{3}}{a_{{6}}}^{3}\\+{
\frac {3\,a_{{1}}{a_{{4}}}^{6}}{32}}+{\frac {{a_{{2}}}^{2}{
a_{{3}}}^{3}{a_{{6}}}^{2}}{72}}+1/24\,{a_{{1}}}^{2}a_{{3}}{
a_{{4}}}^{2}a_{{12}}+1/24\,a_{{2}}a_{{3}}{a_{{4}}}^{2}a_{{
12}}\\+{\frac {13\,{a_{{5}}}^{5}}{600}}+1/8\,a_{{1}}{a_{{8}}}
^{3}+1/12\,a_{{3}}a_{{4}}a_{{6}}a_{{12}}+{\frac {{a_{{5}}}^
{3}a_{{10}}}{60}}+1/30\,{a_{{5}}}^{2}a_{{15}}\\+1/8\,a_{{5}}{
a_{{10}}}^{2}+1/20\,a_{{5}}a_{{20}}+1/30\,a_{{10}}a_{{15}}
.$$

These cycle  indices can be calculated  for large $n$  but the pattern
should be clear. The count of these graphs gives the sequence

$$2, 6, 26, 192, 3014, 127757, 16853750, \\ 7343780765, 10733574184956, 
52867617324773592,\\882178116079222400788, 50227997322550920824045262,
\ldots $$

which points us to [OEIS A007139](https://oeis.org/A007139) where
we find confirmation of this calculation.

This was the Maple code used to obtain these values.

```
with(numtheory);

pet_cycleind_symm :=
proc(n)
local p, s;
option remember;

    if n=0 then return 1; fi;

    expand(1/n*add(a[l]*pet_cycleind_symm(n-l), l=1..n));
end;

pet_autom2cycles :=
proc(src, aut)
local numa, numsubs;
local marks, pos, cycs, cpos, clen;

    numsubs := [seq(src[k]=k, k=1..nops(src))];
    numa := subs(numsubs, aut);

    marks := Array([seq(true, pos=1..nops(aut))]);

    cycs := []; pos := 1;

    while pos <= nops(aut) do
        if marks[pos] then
            clen := 0; cpos := pos;

            while marks[cpos] do
                marks[cpos] := false;
                cpos := numa[cpos];
                clen := clen+1;
            od;

            cycs := [op(cycs), clen];
        fi;

        pos := pos+1;
    od;

    return mul(a[cycs[k]], k=1..nops(cycs));
end;

pet_varinto_cind :=
proc(poly, ind)
local subs1, subs2, polyvars, indvars, v, pot, res;

    res := ind;

    polyvars := indets(poly);
    indvars := indets(ind);

    for v in indvars do
        pot := op(1, v);

        subs1 :=
        [seq(polyvars[k]=polyvars[k]^pot,
             k=1..nops(polyvars))];

        subs2 := [v=subs(subs1, poly)];

        res := subs(subs2, res);
    od;

    res;
end;


pet_flatten_term :=
proc(varp)
        local terml, d, cf, v;

        terml := [];

        cf := varp;
        for v in indets(varp) do
            d := degree(varp, v);
            terml := [op(terml), seq(v, k=1..d)];
            cf := cf/v^d;
        od;

        [cf, terml];
end;



pet_flat2rep_cyc :=
proc(f)
    local p, q, res, cyc, t, len;

    q := 1; res := [];

    for t in f do
        len := op(1, t);
        cyc := [seq(p, p=q+1..q+len-1), q];
        res := [op(res), cyc];
        q := q+len;
    od;

    res;
end;

pet_cycs2table :=
proc(cycs)
    local pairs, cyc, p, ent;

    pairs := [];
    for cyc in cycs do
        pairs :=
        [op(pairs),
         seq([cyc[p], cyc[1 + (p mod nops(cyc))]],
             p = 1 .. nops(cyc))];
    od;

    map(ent->ent[2], sort(pairs, (a,b)->a[1] < b[1]));
end;

pet_cycleind_knn :=
proc(n)
    option remember;
    local cindA, cindB, sind, t1, t2, p, q, cyc1, cyc2,
    flat, len, len1, len2, v1, v2,
    edges, edgeperm, rep, cycsA, cycsB, cycsrc, cyc;

    if n=1 then
        sind := [a[1]];
    else
        sind := pet_cycleind_symm(n);
    fi;

    cindA := 0;

    for t1 in sind do
        for t2 in sind do
            q := 1;

            for v1 in indets(t1) do
                len1 := op(1, v1);

                for v2 in indets(t2) do
                    len2 := op(1, v2);

                    len := lcm(len1, len2);
                    q := q *
                    a[len]^((len1*len2/len) *
                    degree(t1, v1)*degree(t2, v2));
                od;
            od;

            cindA := cindA +
            lcoeff(t1)*lcoeff(t2)*q;
        od;
    od;

    edges := [seq(seq({p, q+n}, q=1..n), p=1..n)];

    cindB := 0;

    for t1 in sind do
        flat := pet_flatten_term(t1);

        cycsA := pet_flat2rep_cyc(flat[2]);
        cycsB := [];
        for cycsrc in cycsA do
            cyc := [];
            for q in cycsrc do
                cyc := [op(cyc), q, q+n];
            od;

            cycsB := [op(cycsB), cyc];
        od;

        rep := pet_cycs2table(cycsB);

        edgeperm :=
        subs([seq(q=rep[q], q=1..2*n)], edges);

        cindB := cindB + flat[1]*
        pet_autom2cycles(edges, edgeperm);
    od;

    (cindA+cindB)/2;
end;

Q :=
proc(n)
    option remember;
    local cind;

    cind := pet_cycleind_knn(n);
    subs([seq(a[p]=2, p=1..n*n)], cind);
end;
```

**Remarks,  per  request,  Dec  2020.**  Here  are  some  observations
concerning reflections. We  need the factorization into  cycles of the
vertices in order to compute the action on the edges. Now a reflection
when  factored  into cycles  must  alternate  between left  and  right
vertices. That means left and  right vertices are interleaved on those
cycles. Hence we  can obtain the factorizations of  all reflections by
taking a  permutation from $S_n$  (which gives the left  vertices) and
doubling  all its  cycles in  length, inserting  a permutation  of the
right vertices, for  a total of $n! \times n!$  reflections. The first
factorial comes from  the permutations of the left  vertices which can
be interleaved with  the right ones in $n!$ ways,  yielding the second
factorial. Now consider the factorization into cycles of the action on
the edges.   Left and right  vertices are  disjoint, so no  matter the
order in which we interleave the right vertices, we get the same shape
of factorizations into cycles (just  permute the right vertices, which
maintains the cycle structure of the edges). Therefore we can take one
representative  for each  term in  $Z(S_n)$, interleave  it with  some
permutation of the  right, and factor that (i.e. factor  the action on
the  edges)  to  get  the  contribution to  $Z(Q_n)$,  which  must  be
multiplied  by $n!$  for the  number  of reflections  covered by  this
term. This  is what the  algorithm does. The $n!$ is canceled  when we
divide by the total number of permutations in the group.

Comment: I have trouble understanding the algorithm for calculating the cycle index when reflections are concerned. I obtain the same results when I consider each of the $n!^2$ pairs of permutations, but it's of course infeasible for larger $n$. Could you describe your approach in more detail? From what I understand, "permutation shape" is just its cycle notation. But two different pairs of permutations with the same cycle notations can contribute different terms to the cycle index when the vertices are additionally reflected. I don't understand how the alternation of components works here.

Comment: I have added some commentary. Please note that the 2017 answer is the reference here.

Comment: Wow, brilliant. Thank you! My mistake was to treat the two permutations and the reflection completely separately, which made the cycle factorization difficult. Embedding the reflection into one of the permutations makes things so much easier and indeed reduces the computational cost from $n!^2$ just to the number of different permutation shapes in $S_n$. This will help me speed up my little project: https://github.com/adamsol/burnside-counter.

Comment: It is now tempting to try to simplify also the case without reflections, so that we don't have to iterate over pairs of permutation shapes at all. But it seems that this case is paradoxically more complicated and it's not possible.

Comment: Good that I could help. I might do some additional simplifications later today.

Answer (score 1):

The question is equivalent to finding all non-isomorphic bipartite graphs with bi-partitions of sizes $n$ and $m$ respectively and is hard to solve in general. In particular there is no simple characterization of such graphs.

If you  need the sequence for the number of such graphs then you can take a look at this oeis entry http://oeis.org/A033995.

If you need to compute such graphs (up to a reasonable number) then your best choice is the tool genbg which you can find in McKay's  nauty package. In some sense genbg is currently the most efficient way to construct such graphs and hence answers your question.

Comment: Yeah I need to find all those non-isomorphic bipartite graphs with sizes $m$ and $n$ in each partition. The sequence above is for the number of bipartite graphs of $n$ vertices. But that number is greater than the number of graphs that I am trying to find. For example if I have four vertices, there are $7$ bipartite graphs but if I'm only taking all the spanning subgraphs of $K_{(2,2)}$ then there are just $6$ of them. The other bipartite graph is a claw which is bipartite with sizes 1 and 3 in each partition.

Comment: @chowching You should be more specific about what you're looking for. Note that in general there is no closed formula for the number of bipartite graphs with bipartitions of cardinality n and m.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm studying Polya Enumeration Theorem now to see if I can apply it to find how many such graphs are there given a certain $n$ and $m$.

Comment: @chowching You can but the formula will most likely require using computer computations.

Comment: @chowching I suggest that for a start you look at Harary's and Palmer's book called "graphical enumeration"

Comment: Okay thank you for the reference. I will look at that.

Answer (score 1):

Adding another answer after receiving a  pointer from a reader of this
thread. We treat the case of spanning subgraphs of $K_{n,n}$ including
reflections. The algorithm has been  greatly simplified. There are two
types of symmetries,  namely shuffles within the two  sets of vertices
and reflections  that map one to  the other.  The first  type has been
simplified  as  follows:   we  continue  to  iterate   over  pairs  of
permutation shapes from $S_n$ but  the contribution to the cycle index
$Z(Q_n)$ is now computed by iterating  over pairs of cycle types (same
length) rather than  single cycles. The second  type (reflections) has
been replaced in  its entirety.  We continue  to produce contributions
by  building   factorized  permutations  consisting  of   cycles  that
alternate between the two classes  of vertices (a precondition of this
problem)  but  whereas in  the  first  version  we would  construct  a
representative of the factored permutation, apply it to the edges, and
factor  the result  into cycles,  the new  version does  not construct
representatives and does no factorization and builds the terms for the
cycle index from first principles, namely that we enumerate the cycles
of  edges (two-sets  of  vertices)  that are  obtained  from a  vertex
permutation  by  choosing  pairs  of  vertices,  counting  these,  and
computing  the lengths  of the  cycles  on which  they reside.   These
optimizations make  for a faster  and much more compact  program. This
was the code:

```
pet_cycleind_symm :=
proc(n)
option remember;

    if n=0 then return 1; fi;

    expand(1/n*add(a[l]*pet_cycleind_symm(n-l), l=1..n));
end;

pet_varinto_cind :=
proc(poly, ind)
local subs1, subs2, polyvars, indvars, v, pot, res;

    res := ind;

    polyvars := indets(poly);
    indvars := indets(ind);

    for v in indvars do
        pot := op(1, v);

        subs1 :=
        [seq(polyvars[k]=polyvars[k]^pot,
             k=1..nops(polyvars))];

        subs2 := [v=subs(subs1, poly)];

        res := subs(subs2, res);
    od;

    res;
end;


pet_flatten_termA :=
proc(varp)
local terml, d, cf, v;

    terml := [];

    cf := varp;
    for v in indets(varp) do
        d := degree(varp, v);
        terml := [op(terml), [op(1,v), d]];
        cf := cf/v^d;
    od;

    [cf, terml];
end;

pet_cycleind_knn :=
proc(n)
option remember;
local cindA, cindB, sind, t1, t2, term, res,
    flat, flat1, flat2, len, l1, l2, cycs, uidx, vidx,
    u, v, inst1;

    if n=1 then
        sind := [a[1]];
    else
        sind := pet_cycleind_symm(n);
    fi;

    cindA := 0;

    for t1 in sind do
        flat1 := pet_flatten_termA(t1);

        for t2 in sind do
            flat2 := pet_flatten_termA(t2);

            res := 1;

            for u in flat1[2] do
                l1 := op(1, u);

                for v in flat2[2] do
                    l2 := op(1, v);

                    len := lcm(l1, l2);
                    res := res *
                    a[len]^(op(2, u)*op(2, v)
                            *l1*l2/len);
                od;
            od;

            cindA := cindA + flat1[1]*flat2[1]*res;
        od;
    od;

    cindB := 0;

    for term in sind do
        flat := pet_flatten_termA(term);

        cycs := map(cyc -> [2*cyc[1], cyc[2]], flat[2]);
        res := 1;

        # edges on different cycles of different sizes
        for uidx to nops(cycs) do
            u := cycs[uidx];

            for vidx from uidx+1 to nops(cycs) do
                v := cycs[vidx];

                l1 := op(1, u); l2 := op(1, v);
                res := res *
                a[lcm(l1, l2)]^((l1*l2/2/lcm(l1, l2))*
                                op(2, u)*op(2, v));
            od;
        od;

        # edges on different cycles of the same size
        for uidx to nops(cycs) do
            u := cycs[uidx];

            l1 := op(1, u); inst1 := op(2, u);
            # a[l1]^(1/2*inst1*(inst1-1)*l1*l1/2/l1)
            res := res *
            a[l1]^(1/2*inst1*(inst1-1)*l1/2);
        od;

        # edges on identical cycles of some size
        for uidx to nops(cycs) do
            u := cycs[uidx];

            l1 := op(1, u); inst1 := op(2, u);
            if type(l1/2, even) then
                # a[l1]^((l1/2)^2/l1);
                res := res *
                (a[l1]^(l1/4))^inst1;
            else
                # a[l1/2]^(l1/2/(l1/2))*a[l1]^(((l1/2)^2-l1/2)/l1)
                res := res *
                (a[l1/2]*a[l1]^(l1/4-1/2))^inst1;
            fi;
        od;


        cindB := cindB + flat[1]*res;
    od;

    (cindA+cindB)/2;
end;
```

This will produce  the following data for  the non-isomorphic spanning
subgraphs of  $K_{6,6}$ including reflections classified  according to
the number of edges:

$${z}^{36}+{z}^{35}+2\,{z}^{34}+4\,{z}^{33}+10\,{z}^{32}
+20\,{z}^{31}+50\,{z}^{30}+99\,{z}^{29}+227\,{z}^{28}
\\ +458\,{z}^{27}+934\,{z}^{26}+
1711\,{z}^{25}+3057\,{z}^{24}+4889\,{z}^{23}+7400\,{z}^{22}
\\ +10071\,{z}^{21}+12755\,{z}^{20}+14524\,{z}^{19}
+15331\,{z}^{18}+14524\,{z}^{17}+12755\,{z}^{16}
\\+10071\,{z}^{15}+7400\,{z}^{14}+4889\,{z}^{13}+
3057\,{z}^{12}+1711\,{z}^{11}+934\,{z}^{10}
\\ +458\,{z}^{9}+227\,{z}^{8}+99\,{z}^{7}+50\,{z}^{6}+20\,{z}^{5}
+10\,{z}^{4}+4\,{z}^{3}+2\,{z}^{2}+z+1.$$

i.e. the  value four  for three  edges counts, first,  a set  of three
edges, not connected, second, two edges  sharing a vertex and a single
edge, third, three edges emanating from  the same vertex and fourth, a
path of three edges.

**Addendum.** We  may use  Burnside as  shown below  if we  are not
interested in classifying according to the number of edges and require
only the total count. This gives:

```
Q :=
proc(n)
    option remember;
    local cind;

    cind := pet_cycleind_knn(n);
    subs([seq(a[p]=2, p=1..n*n)], cind);
end;
```

The  routine that  substitutes polynomials  into cycle  indices is  no
longer needed in this case. Observe that further simplification at the
expense of readability is possible by not computing the cycle index at
all and setting all $a[p]$ to  two during the computation of what used
to be the cycle index.

**Remark, Dec  2020.** We can  in fact optimize away  all flattening
operations and use the fact that Maple monomials i.e. the terms of the
cycle  index are  perfectly sufficient  to implement  a multiset  data
structure where the variables represent  cycles of some length and the
degrees,  the  number of  instances,  as  is  of course  the  standard
semantics  of cycle  indices.  This is  shown  below. (Duplicate  code
omitted.)

```
pet_cycleind_knn :=
proc(n)
option remember;
local cindA, cindB, sind, t1, t2, term,
    res, len, len1, len2, cycs, uidx, vidx, interlv,
    u, v, inst, q;

    if n=1 then
        sind := [a[1]];
    else
        sind := pet_cycleind_symm(n);
    fi;

    cindA := 0;

    for t1 in sind do
        for t2 in sind do
            q := 1;

            for u in indets(t1) do
                len1 := op(1, u);

                for v in indets(t2) do
                    len2 := op(1, v);

                    len := lcm(len1, len2);
                    q := q *
                    a[len]^((len1*len2/len) *
                    degree(t1, u)*degree(t2, v));
                od;
            od;

            cindA := cindA +
            lcoeff(t1)*lcoeff(t2)*q;
        od;
    od;

    cindB := 0;

    interlv := subs({seq(a[q]=a[2*q], q=1..n)}, sind);
    for term in interlv do
        termvars := indets(term); res := 1;

        # edges on different cycles of different sizes
        for uidx to nops(termvars) do
            u := op(uidx, termvars);
            len1 := op(1, u);

            for vidx from uidx+1 to nops(termvars) do
                v := op(vidx, termvars);
                len2 := op(1, v);

                res := res *
                a[lcm(len1, len2)]
                ^((len1*len2/2/lcm(len1, len2))*
                  degree(term, u)*degree(term, v));
            od;
        od;

        # edges on different cycles of the same size
        for u in termvars do
            len := op(1, u); inst := degree(term, u);
            # a[len]^(1/2*inst*(inst-1)*len*len/2/len)
            res := res *
            a[len]^(1/4*inst*(inst-1)*len);
        od;

        # edges on identical cycles of some size
        for u in termvars do
            len := op(1, u); inst := degree(term, u);
            if type(len/2, even) then
                # a[len]^((len/2)^2/len);
                res := res *
                (a[len]^(len/4))^inst;
            else
                # a[len/2]^(len/2/(len/2))
                # *a[len]^(((len/2)^2-len/2)/len)
                res := res *
                (a[len/2]*a[len]^(len/4-1/2))^inst;
            fi;
        od;

        cindB := cindB + lcoeff(term)*res;
    od;

    (cindA+cindB)/2;
end;


Q :=
proc(n)
    option remember;
    local cind;

    cind := pet_cycleind_knn(n);
    subs([seq(a[p]=2, p=1..n*n)], cind);
end;
```