# Count of connected bipartite graphs with even number of vertices up to isomorphism

Tags: graph-theory, combinations

Suppose graph $G$ is connected bipartite with an even number $n$ of vertices.  How can I count the number of such graphs that are not isomorphic?

For example if $n=2$ the answer is $1$, if $n=4$ the answer is $3$, and if $n=6$ the answer is $17$.

I would so appreciate if someone can help me!

Comment: look it again pls

Comment: @hardmath nothing else for example if $n=2$ the answer is $1$ , if $n=4$ the answer is $3$ and if $n=6$ the answer is $17$...

Comment: @hardmath $n$ is equal number of vertex in graph

Comment: That is so important to your problem that it needs to be stated in the Question itself, not just a comment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44387/discussion-between-saman-sasani-and-hardmath).

Comment: This [MSE link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1151538/) could prove useful reading.

Comment: See [OEIS sequence A05142](http://oeis.org/A005142) and links there.

Comment: I have edited in the role of $n$ being an even number of vertices, which at least restricts us to a finite count (depending on $n$).

Comment: @RobertIsrael THX about your link 
:-)