# Number of non-isomorphic k-partite graphs.

Tags: graph-theory

There is a set of vertices and it is divided into $k$ independent sets. The cardinalities of these sets are following: $a_{1},a_{2},...,a_{k}$

> How many non-isomorphic graphs determined on these sets are there?

I hope that someone will help me.

Regards.

Comment: Where does this problem come from? The answer is, as far as I know, not known even for bi-partite graphs.. See for example https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2321657/how-many-distinct-non-isomorphic-bipartite-graphs-with-parts-of-size-m-and-n

Comment: The question is easy if you ask for the number of different labeled such graphs, but "isomorphic" makes it very hard.

Comment: This [MSE link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1151538/) treats the case of non-isomorphic bipartite graphs.